# Regex validation of table schema and name

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I have an API that performs some query on a table that the caller specifies. The table name is placed in the query via string replace, and so is a risk for SQL injection.

Example:

```
tableName = req.body.tableName;

sql = "SELECT * FROM <<TABLE_NAME>>;";
sql = sql.replace("<<TABLE_NAME>>", tableName);
```

I'm required to keep this query dynamic, as we don't want to redeploy this code every time we add a new table. In other words, I can't just maintain a list of valid table names.

So for the purposes of keeping this safe from sql injection, is it sufficient to do a regex validation on the table name? We can be certain the table name will always be of the format `schema.table_name` where table_name will be only a-z, 0-9, -, _

Is there any sql injection that could slip past this table name regex?

`^myschema\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since minus is not a valid character in a tablename, you could change your regex to just:

```
^myschema\.\w+$
```

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

There is no risk of injection.

---

Most databases allow special characters, even spaces and minuses, in table names if special syntax is used, eg

```
MySQL: `my stupid table-name!`
Postgres: "my stupid table-name!"
SQL Server: [my stupid table-name!]
```

It is poor practice to allow non-standard characters in names in the first place, and it would be fine to deny such names in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign cannot be used as an identifier in SQL. In the case of table names, I don't think it will lead to SQL injection attacks, but if you allow minus signs in column names, subtraction can be injected.
In the case of MySQL, the following SQL statement will return all users, not just 'tom'. This is because of the implicit type conversion that occurs when subtracting from a string.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE myschema.user-0 = 'tom'
```

The workaround is to exclude the minus sign or quote the identifier. The following will not result in a SQL injection attack.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `myschema`.`user-0` = 'tom'.
```

The above is the way to write for MySQL, and the way to write for standard SQL is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE "myschema"."user-0" = 'tom'
```